# First row of array is the first line

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment, arrays

I want to code an array on which the first row would be the first line.
I used the array environment.

Here is what I get but it's not what I want (the line is centered on the second row).

[image: array]

Here is my code

```
$\begin{array}{ll}
C = \{ \,
(\bar q(0),\bar q(T)) 
\, |\, 
&\theta_i(0) = \theta_i(T)\;\; i=1,2, \\
&x(0)=0,\, x(T) = x_T \mbox{ (fixed)},\\
&q^0(0)=0\, \}.
\end{array}$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Write `\begin{array}[t]{ll}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- Use `\mid` to denote the conditioning operation
- Suppress the intercolumn whitespace between the two columns of the `array` environment
- Load the `amsmath` package and use `\text` instead of `\mbox`
- Consider using slightly-enlarged curly braces and outer round parentheses, using `\bigl` and `\bigr`. If you choose to do so, you should also use `\bigm|` instead of `\mid`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}[t]{l@{}l}
C = \bigl\{ \, \bigl(\bar{q}(0),\bar{q}(T)\bigr) \bigm| {}
   & \theta_i(0) = \theta_i(T), \quad i=1,2, \\
   & x(0)=0, x(T) = x_T \text{ (fixed)},\\
   & q^0(0)=0 \, \bigr\}.
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```